# Missing files in Android SDK tools directory

Tags: android-sdk-tools

I did some upgrades with the Android SDK Manager and now I am getting notices that some files in the tools/ directory are missing.

When I try to start 'monitor', I get a message that hprof-conv is missing:

[image: monitor screenshot]

And I'm also getting compile errors from Android Studio that it can't find the package 'android.annotation.SuppressLint' which, from my research, is supposed to be in tools/support/annotations.jar.

I have all the Android tools installed:

[image: SDK Manager]

What am I missing?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Looks similar to [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72455) from yesterday. There's also [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419) which mentions hprof-conv and contains a suggested workaround.

Comment: Thanx, @Michael.  That looks like the problem.  If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as such.